# SignalR client hangs on start() on the second session

Tags: winforms, asp.net-core, signalr

I have a ASP.Net core web-app published to IIS, the web-app uses SignalR to display notifications. I also have a desktop windows forms application is used to connect to a fingerprint device and is also used to send notification to the web-app that a person just entered so i can display a notification on the web-app about that person.
And everything works fine with one session of the web-app, but if i open another tab for example or browse the web-app from another computer the second one hangs on the `connection.start()` until i close the first session. and this drives me crazy.

Here is the code.

ASP.net core Hub

```
public class SignalRServer : Hub
{
    public async Task displayNotification()
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("displayNotification");
    }
}
```

Javascript client code

```
let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
.withUrl("/SignalRServer")
.configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
.build();

connection.on("displayNotification", () => {
    getLatestNotification();
});

connection.start();
```

The windows forms app has two projects the first one is .NET framework 4.5 which uses the fingerprint device API to connect to the device. And the second project is .NET standard which contains the SignalR HubConnection code to connect to server, and HubConnection is used in the first project to connect and send notifications.

windows forms app Hub connection code in .NET standard

```
public class HubNotification
{
    HubConnection connection;
    public HubNotification(string Ip)
    {
        connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
         .WithUrl(Ip + "/SignalRServer")

         .Build();
         connection.StartAsync();
    }

    public async Task ConnectAsync()
    {

        await connection.StartAsync();

    }

    public  void SendNotAsync()
    {
         connection.InvokeAsync("displayNotification");

    }

}
```

then in the first project i use `ConnectAsync` and `SendNotAsync` to send notification when i person enters.
I don't think there is a problem with the desktop app but i posted the code anyway.
I have read that there is a problem with signalR and multiple session but didn't find any solution.

Comment: So the problem is that the second session wouldn't start until you close your first session?

Comment: Yes exactly, and if commented the connection.start() in the client code everything works great

Comment: Try to ```console.log``` your connection ID to see if they are different, if they are the same, your problem is the duplicated session.

Comment: i will try it today and tell you the result

Comment: so what is the result?

Comment: the id is zero
and another note the problem doesn't appear on my computer it only appear on the client server, we both have windows 10 and hosting on iis